# Alfresco 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler' with Spring Webflux Starter

Tags: java, spring, maven, netty, alfresco

I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler` exception when starting Alfresco but already cleaned my dependencies and only get `io.netty` dependencies from Spring Boot Starter Webflux.

My stack trace is [here](https://pastebin.com/SrhV0uer)
Dependency tree [here](https://pastebin.com/hH0JL97Y)

I don't really know what to do now because nothing seems to work out. The whole app runs on Docker and everything worked fine before we used the WebClient from Webflux.

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard to debug, but it's usually a dependency conflict.

In your pom.xml try to exclude nitty from webflex dependency add the following to your webflex dependency.

```
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
       <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

then add netty dependency separately, go to [mvn Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=netty) and search for the netty dependency that suit you. or try this one.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.42.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It sadly throws the same exception. This is really a weird one as nothing seems to fix it.